# GridView item not expanding to show content

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, nine-patch

This may be the opposite question from [Android GridView Items Resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483428/android-gridview-items-resizing)

I have a GridView that is set to display a custom layout made from a LinearLayout with a 9-patch background and a TextView.  The LinearLayout has a 10dp padding set so the TextView stays in the center patch.

When I've tested data to expand the TextView, the LinearLayout also appears to expand (yay!) but the GridView is cutting off the bottom.  In the image below, you can see that the bottom right element has the bottom-right curvature cut off.

[image: Screenshot of GridView]

MyClasses.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_classes);
    notebookGrid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.NotebookGrid);

    ArrayList<String> class1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "Ms. Soldan's Class"));
    ArrayList<String> class2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("2", "Ms. Perry's Class"));
    ArrayList<String> class3 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("3", "Ms. Panjwani's Class"));
    ArrayList<String> class4 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("4", "Ms. Smith's Really Awesome Super Cool Class of Many Geniuses"));

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> classArray = new ArrayList<>();
    classArray.add(class1);
    classArray.add(class2);
    classArray.add(class3);
    classArray.add(class4);
    notebookGrid.setAdapter(new MyClassesAdapter(this, classArray));
}
```

MyClassesAdapter.java:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ArrayList<String> thisClass = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder vh;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_class_notebook, parent,false);
        vh = new ViewHolder(convertView,R.id.NotebookTitle);
        convertView.setTag(vh);
    } else {
        vh = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
        vh.TitleView.setText(thisClass.get(1));
    return convertView;
}
```

grid_class_notebook.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/notebook">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:id="@+id/NotebookTitle"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_my_classes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="25dp"
        android:text="@string/classes_title"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/NotebookGrid"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How do I get the element or row to grow taller in response to a larger TextView child?

Comment: add the code for `activity_my_classes.xml`

Comment: added activity_my_classes

Answer (score 0):

So this only took me a month to answer for myself.  What was happening here was that the GridView itself was short but the item itself was actually properly sized.  It had never occurred to me to try to scroll the notebooks, but I did that today and the rest of the image appeared.

Basically the error was that GridView had a height of "wrap_content".  I've changed it to a height of 0dp and added a tag of weight=1 since I'll be adding some other elements below the GridView eventually.  New xml code for activity_my_classes:

```
<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/NotebookGrid"/>
```